# Is it possible to flash an app via custom recovery? If it is, will it become a system app?

Tags: recovery-mode, system-apps, side-loading

I wanted to have an app as a system app without rooting it. I was wondering if it's possible to flash/install an app through custom recovery as we do with Gapps and other stuff.

So, I came up with an idea to flash it via recovery, but I don't know whether it will work or not. If not, is there any other way to make an app a system app without rooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible and has been done many times. The method to do so is explained in this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-android-apps-recovery-zip/).

Briefly, the main steps from the provided link are following:

1. Download any similar zip [template](https://mega.nz/#!R4AggZjK!mVwpFp9lFtctNA51NubD1hr-Wm-zMREdJVLI3LXY4Yc)
2. Extract it; there will be 2 folders - `META-INF` & `system`
3. Make a folder with the name `app` inside the `system` folder
4. Paste your APK files in the `app` folder
5. Zip `META-INF` & `system` into a file
6. Flash it